# Storing integers from Console to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Im writing a program that asks the console for x numbers from the console. If they pick the number 4, then 4 different numbers should be stored. Then the program must store all these inputed numbers in an array, and then add the numbers together and print it out in the console.

So, i tried to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write out a number: ");
        int[] x = int[].Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

and apparently you cant read in array elements from the console on that way, so do I need to store them inside an variabel and then add them to an new array?

Comment: `so do I need to store them inside an variabel and then add them to an new array?` Did you _try_ that?

Comment: Ive programmed in 2 weeks and Im sorry if im a bit newbie to you but im trying to improve. So if u helped me instead of mocking the world would be a better place for all.

Comment: @user2669196 Telling you to try something that you yourself considered doing isn't mocking you.  First off, it's a legitimate question.  If you tried it and failed then you should be showing us your attempts, as it will help us realize what you do/don't understand.  If you didn't, it's a rather polite way of telling you that you *should* try it.  It *is* you obligation to put in some effort before asking questions here; if you knew what you should do and just didn't bother to actually attempt it then it is *you* who are acting in appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Writeline("Enter the number of numbers to add: ");
//Yes, I know you should actually do validation here
var numOfNumbersToAdd = int.Parse(Console.Readline());

int value;
int[] arrayValues = new int[numOfNumbersToAdd];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfNumbersToAdd; i++)
{
    Console.Writeline("Please enter a value: ");
    //Primed read
    var isValidValue = int.TryParse(Console.Readline(), out value);
    while(!isValidValue) //Loop until you get a value
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, please try again: "); //Tell the user why they are entering a value again...
        isValidValue = int.TryParse(Console.Readline(), out value);
    }
    arrayValues[i] = value; //store the value in the array
}
//I would much rather do this with LINQ and Lists, but the question asked for arrays.
var sum = 0;
foreach(var v in arrayValues)
{
    sum += v;
}
Console.Writeline("Sum {0}", sum);
```

Comment: This solution could be simplified by using Lists and LINQ and would just look a lot cleaner, but that's probably an interesting bit for another day.